# Qt Widget In Designer but still getting errors

Tags: c++, qt

I have made a custom widget + plugin and implemented it into my Qt Designer. From there I then linked the `*.lib` file into my test application. Error:

> mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall GLineEdit::GLineEdit(class QWidget *)" (??0GLineEdit@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_MainWindow@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)

which doesnt make much sense as I have the correct includes in my the `setupUi()` function. Here is the relevant source code of the projects:

[Widget Project](https://gist.github.com/NickJohn547745/f3425f0801837ea3b43b607cb50e9e8a)

[Plugin Project](https://gist.github.com/NickJohn547745/70e9b8127d60503ed0edca1dc7c9de8c)

[Temporary Project](https://gist.github.com/NickJohn547745/b9bed32f668013edfddbc898bb8b3783)

Comment: It is better to create a [mcve] than linking to your complete source code.

Comment: The link you've provided doesn't tell us anything about the `pro` file. Such error typically occurs when you just don't link against the respective lib. Just because you have the includes doesn't mean that the building process will succeed.

Comment: @eyllanesc .pro file added.

Comment: @rbaleksandar .pro file added.

Comment: @eyllanesc i added all of the separate projects

Comment: Windows 10 - 32bit

Comment: @eyllanesc MSVC 2015 - 32bit

Comment: @eyllanesc and I apologize. I meant to say Windows 10 - 64bit

Comment: @eyllanesc I added my widget libraries to my pro file. What are you referencing?

Comment: @eyllanesc Correct! I can place it and everything in the designer. Just doesnt run the due to the stated error even after a clean all + qmake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150232/discussion-between-nicholas-johnson-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @NicholasJohnson How did it go?

Comment: @eyllanesc I would like to talk a bit more to finish off the project.

Comment: What is missing from your project?

Comment: I didn't get to have you follow up after the restart of my machine.

Comment: Pass me your teamviewer credentials via chat